# Simplifying an equation in which all the terms are integrals with respect to the same variable

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions

I have an equation in the following form:

```
Integrate[A[x], x] + Integrate[B[x], x] == Integrate[C[x],x]
```

How can I simplify this equation to get:

```
A[x] + B[x] == C[x]
```

As far as I have examined, even `FullSimplify` or `Reduce` can not eliminate the integrals in this kind of equations.

Comment: An indefinite integral has an undefined constant. Therefore, from the first equation it only follows: `A[x] + B[x] == C[x]+const`

Comment: The integrals have undefined constants, not the integrands.  It follows from the equality of the integrals that `A[x] + B[x] == C[x]`. (It's easy to see, conversely, that if we have `A[x] = 2x`, `B[x] = 1`, and `C[x] = 2x`, so that `A[x] + B[x] == C[x] + 1`, then `Integrate[A[x], x] + Integrate[B[x], x] == Integrate[C[x],x]` does not hold.)

Answer (score 4):

In calculus class we might differentiate both sides:

```
ApplySides[D[#, x] &,
 Integrate[a[x], x] + Integrate[b[x], x] == Integrate[c[x], x]
 ]

(*  a[x] + b[x] == c[x]  *)
```

([Avoid beginning your symbols with a capital.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/4999)  For instance `C` is a `Protected` symbol in Mathematica.)